# Meaning of >> in C#

Tags: c#, syntax

Maybe it's a silly question but I cannot search any result in google/stackoverflow by keying the code.

My question is that what's the meaning of ">>" in code "i = x >> 1;"

Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt18et0d.aspx

Comment: search google for: i = x >> 1; C#

Comment: Its a shift operator and can easily be found if you search for it on the internet.

Comment: If you have a search that includes symbols, try symbolhound.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

'>>' is a binary shift operator. It shifts the bits of it's left operand (x in your example) to the right by the number specified in it's right operand (1 in your example).

Example:
Say the value of x is 16. This, in binary, is 10000.

```
x = 16; //     x = 0b10000 = 16
```

So "x >> 1" has the value 1000 in binary, or 8 in decimal.

```
i = x >> 1; // i = 0b01000 =  8
```

Searching for symbols on google and stack overflow is difficult without text around the symbols. Try using http://symbolhound.com/ when searching for symbols in the future.

Comment: Functionally speaking, `a >> b` is the same as `a / Math.Pow(2, b)` (integer division throws away the remainder in the same way) - in other words `a >> 1` == `a / 2`, `a >> 2` == `a / 4` etc. The left-shift operator (`<<`) unsurprisingly, does the exact opposite, with the overflow being on the most-significant-bit, rather than the least-significant-bit. (e.g for a signed 32 bit integer `a`, with the value `-2147483648` (the negative limit value), the binary representation is `0x10000000000000000000000000000000`, bit-shifting this `a << 1` would give you `0`, as the MSB would 'drop off'.

Comment: Isn't `a >> b` (slightly) quicker at runtime than `a / Math.Pow(2, b)`, though?

Comment: I should think this is the case; my point is that the result is the same, the bit shift operators are conceptually a special case of exponentiation.

Comment: Agreed - just making it clear why people use the former in some cases.